# WP-API call function

Tags: wp-api

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

My website API: https://examplee.tld/wp-json

If visit my API please run my own plugin: https://examplee.tld/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/myplugin.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: MYPLUGIN
 */

// If visit my https://examplee.tld/wp-json API, run this command:
// error_log ( 'test' );

?>
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Here's [the REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/). You probably want [Extending the REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/). What specifically do you want to do: hook all REST API requests, or add a new endpoint, or something else?

Comment: Is this the same question as [your last one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/386775/wp-api-new-variable) - you want to add a new property to the top-level JSON returned?